Linux Deleted File Recovery by isof command
I accidently deleted a directory that has hundreds of sub directories and thousands of files. I would like to get those deleted files recovered.
What I have tried:

I verified one process is still having those files open therefore those files haven't been fully deleted from the disk.

I tried to use lsof | grep '(deleted)' to locate those files and managed to recover one file at a time, however there are thousands of files to be recovered and I failed to find a way to do bulk recovery.


I'm wondering if there is a way to recover all of them in bulk and keep the files' names and folder structure the same as before?
lsof output excerpt:
    qe 1042 CENSORED 2680r   REG    8,1 13011367     0 312557 /home/CENSORED/file_a.epub (deleted)
    qe 1042 CENSORED 2698r   REG    8,1 12560738     0 312077 /home/CENSORED/b/file_b.zip (deleted)
    qe 1042 CENSORED 2744r   REG    8,1 12805603     0 312623 /home/CENSORED/c/sub_directory/file_c.pdf (deleted)

Thanks a lot!

This question is similar to: Tool for File Recover | Deleted Files Recovery. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: How to recover deleted files?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
